# Drawing circles on a line (with the center of each circle at the intersection of the previous circle and the line)

Tags: geometry

Sorry for the horrible title, feel free to come up with something smarter.

I want to produce the following result:

[My desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyGSf.png)

[image]

To describe it shortly:

1. I have a line of finite length.
2. I want to draw circles, their centers must always be on said line.
3. The circles are drawn from left to right, getting gradually smaller. Their radii follow a function (see next image).
4. The center of a new circle must always be exactly at the (right) intersection of the line and the previous circle.

The function for the radii looks like this:

[Exemplary function that defines the circles radii depending on the position of their respective centers on the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2gPp.png)

[image]

I do know how to calculate my circles iteratively (one by one) but I want to implement this feature in Python (I'd love to use something else, but can't) and performance is relevant.

Is there a way of "vectorizing" this calculation, i.e. to calculate the total number of circles and their respective radii in a non-iterative way (so I can crunch processing times down with Numpy)?

EDIT: A little gif to show the process I'm talking about:
https://imgflip.com/gif/41z4dr

Comment: What are you referring to with *start value* and *end value*?

Comment: With _start value_ and _end value_ I refer to the radii of the first and last circle on the line (since the line is finite, this pattern has a clear beginning and end).

Comment: That's what I expected, but if the line segment is two units long, a circle with radius 4 and center on the line segment would not intersect the line segment.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I didn't pay attention when I made up these boundaries... I changed the caption of the picture so it would make more sense.

Comment: It would help if you added details of your iterative calculations with an actual example giving the desired result. Also, the circles in the first image appear to have common tangents. Is that what you are trying to produce?

Comment: I hope this gif helps

Answer (score 1):

***contains a mistake: incorrect problem statement***

I am not sure what you mean when you refer to "the total number  of circles", but if I understand correctly, you want to find the centre $x_n$ of the $n$-th circle in your sequence. From the construction, it is clear that $\forall k(x_{k+1}=x_k+f(k))$. From this, we can easily derive by induction that $$x_n = x_0 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {\Big(4-2\sqrt{\frac k 2}\Big)} = x_0 + 4n-\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {\sqrt k}$$
Therefore, the only way to make your computation fast is to compute $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {\sqrt k}$ effectively. For example, you can use a formula $$\sum_{t=1}^n{\sqrt t} = C+\frac 23n^{\frac 23}+\frac 12n^{\frac 12}+n^{-\frac 12}(\frac 1{24}-\frac 1 {1920n^2}+\frac 1 {9216n^4}-\cdots)$$ ([source](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram09.pdf))

In the formula, $C$ can be precalculated to the desired accuracy $C=\frac 1 {4\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty {k^{-\frac 32}}$ prior to the calculations and stored as a constant. This way, chopping the formula at $\frac 1 {n^4}$ term, gives a very high numerical accuracy, note that if $n=2$, $\frac 1 {9216n^2}$ is already $0.00000678168\dots$ . Every calculation then consist only of exponentiations instead of a costly sum or iterative steps.

The final form is $$x_n = x_0 + 4n - \frac 1{\sqrt 2}(C + \frac 23(n-1)\sqrt {n-1} + \frac 12 \sqrt {n-1} + \frac 1{\sqrt {n-1}} (\frac 1{24} - \frac 1{1920(n-1)^2}+\frac 1{9216(n-1)^4}))$$
You can add more terms at the end to increase the accuracy of the calculations, but the change would be minuscule. I also did not simplify the equation as it does not affect the speed of calculations.

Edit: $\forall n\ge 8 (f(n)\le 0)$ which means that you will only have 8 circles which defeats the purpose of optimization. Nevertheless, the presented solution works just as well for any coefficients in the formula $f(x)$.

Comment: Can we really make the assumption of your first equation? It seems to me like you're calculating the sum of all circle-radii for $k \in N_0$. But I thought the circles might be at non-integer positions, too.

Comment: @TheBeautifulOrc It is specified in the statement of the original problem that the circles are drawn based on the previous one in the sequence, which is not possible if $k\in\mathbb R \backslash \mathbb N_0$. Additionally, the provided gif shows a sequence of circles with nonnegative indices.

Comment: The problem is that $\forall k(x_{k+1} = x_k + f(k))$ is incorrect. It should rather be $\forall k(x_{k+1} = x_k + f(x_k))$. I might have been unclear about that but the radius-function takes the position of the circle as it's input argument **not** it's index.

Comment: Oh wow, I actually just noticed that I misunderstood the problem. Should I leave my answer for now, until (and if) I fix it? Or does it make sense to remove it?

Comment: No I think the answer is still valuable and may be a great starting point for further iterations on this problem. I'd definitely not delete it but rather clearly mark it as "flawed" so nobody gets confused.